# How to create an array of the same length as a Vec?

Tags: arrays, vector, rust

I am trying to create an array of the same length as a vector, in rust but I keep getting errors.

```
//my code
fn main() {
    let v = vec![1,2,3];
    let len = v.len();
    let a: [i32; len] = [0; len];
    println!("{:?}", a);
}
```

The Error Message :

```
   Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error[E0435]: attempt to use a non-constant value in a constant
 --> src/main.rs:4:18
  |
3 |     let len = v.len();
  |     ------- help: consider using `const` instead of `let`: `const len`
4 |     let a: [i32; len] = [0; len];
  |                  ^^^ non-constant value

error[E0435]: attempt to use a non-constant value in a constant
 --> src/main.rs:4:29
  |
3 |     let len = v.len();
  |     ------- help: consider using `const` instead of `let`: `const len`
4 |     let a: [i32; len] = [0; len];
  |                             ^^^ non-constant value

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0435`.
error: could not compile `playground` due to 2 previous errors
```

If I declare len as a const

```
fn main() {
    let v = vec![1,2,3];
    const len: usize = v.len();
    let a: [i32; len] = [0; len];
    println!("{:?}", a);
}
```

I get this error:

```
  Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error[E0435]: attempt to use a non-constant value in a constant
 --> src/main.rs:3:24
  |
3 |     const len: usize = v.len();
  |     ---------          ^ non-constant value
  |     |
  |     help: consider using `let` instead of `const`: `let len`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0435`.
error: could not compile `playground` due to previous error
```

Why exactly is the above code giving me an error. In other languages I can assign the length of a vector or arraylist to a constant variable. Even though the length of a vec is mutable but the length of vec at the time of assignment must have been a constant value. So why am I getting this error?

And also how can I create an array of the same length as vector in rust?

Comment: The whole point of a Rust array is that its length is knowable at compile time (i.e., it's a compile-time constant). A vector's length is only knowable at runtime. So, you cannot create an array whose length is the same as a vector. Other languages that claim to be able to create arrays dynamically probably aren't putting them on the stack and almost certainly can't treat them as `Copy`.

Comment: @BallpointBen C# is one of the few modern languages I can think of that lets you do this (`stackalloc`) and since C# 7.2 doesn't require an unsafe context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays in Rust are values (similar to arrays in C/C++) with contiguous storage for the elements where the array value lives, in comparison to languages like Java, C#, Python, etc., where contiguous storage for the elements is allocated elsewhere (the heap) and referenced from an array-typed variable.

Because of this, the size of an array in Rust *must* be known at compile time, because that determines how many bytes of memory are required for the array value.

If you want the flexibility of dynamically-sized arrays, then you need a separate allocation pointed at by a fixed-size struct that will manage the allocation for you.  Thankfully, Rust comes with one of these types!  It's called `Vec`!

Comment: Thanks for answering. I had another question that I had asked, why I was not able to assign const to the the length of the vector.  
For Example : const len: usize = v.len();
this should have been valid.

Comment: @Aditya `const` declares a _compile-time_ constant, so the value must be fully known during compilation. However, `v.len()` does not have a known value at compile time. You declare run-time immutable values with `let` and run-time mutable values with `let mut`. If you are coming from C++, `const` in Rust is more like C++'s `constexpr` than C++'s `const`.